# input statement showing EOFerror

Tags: python, string, list, loops, input

My code is showing EOFError for input statement when i am giving an input like described below.what is the problem such that it return EOFError as an error.

input should be like

3,
2,
5 10
2, 
10 5
2,
5 15

commas refer to next line

output should be like

YES,
NO,
NO

````
n=int(input())
t1=0
while n>=t1:
  t=int(input())
  l=[]
  for i in range(t):
      val=int(input())
      l.append(val)
  icream=5
  chefmoney=0
  for i in l:
      if(i==icream):
          chefmoney=chefmoney+icream
      if(i>icream) and (i-icream>chefmoney):
          t=False
      if(i>icream) and (i-icream==chefmoney):
          t=True
  t1=t1+1
if(t==True):
  print("YES")
if(t==False):
  print("NO")

      ```
````

Comment: Which version of Python are you using?

Comment: @IainShelvington It looks like Python 3, but the distinction is irrelevant to the posted code since `input()` is being forced to `int` and the prints all have parens.

Comment: In your sample input, each number should be on its own line, but there are several missing commas which you are using to indicate newlines.  Was that intentional?  If so, then fix it so that each number appears on its own line.  Your code will not work otherwise.

Comment: Yes the not using of commas was intentional. Thank you for ur suggestion I'll try it in my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are reading more lines than are available.

```
n=int(input())
t1=0
while n>=t1
```

should be:

```
n = int(input())
t1 = 0
while t1 < n:
```

When starting the index from `0` compare the index strictly less than the maximum (sentinel) value .  In order to compare index <= sentinel value you would need to start the index at `1`.

I also re-arranged your comparison because it is traditional to write that comparison expression as `index (comparison) sentinel` rather than `sentinel (comparison) index`.

This is an example of the "off by one" error that you frequently see mentioned in software development.